# Amd Radeon HD 7400M series driver not found

Tags: drivers, radeon

where can i find the driver of AMD Radeon HD 7400m Series For Win 8...
I tried too Many Times But Cannot find...Always this note has show that "you hardware not compatible with your driver"

Answer (score 0):

Download the original drivers from: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx.

After extracting the archive, run `sh ./ati-driver-installer-x86.x86_64.run`.

That helped me, I hope it will help you.

Comment: if you are looking for windows 8 this is the wrong room for you.